# How to Send and Receive HTTP Requests and Response in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I don't know how to make Http connection with HTTP server using blackberry. I want to send argument with URL and I have to get a response from the server using Http connection I don't how to do this.pls provide me with some code snippet to handle this situation.

Comment: The sample code for http communication is provided with JDE. It will definitely help you.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0 ? What happens?